# Laravel database connection times out but can connect via mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, centos

I'm facing a very weird issue here and have spent a lot of time trying to debug.

My app resides in AWS environment. My staging environment is just an EC2 (CentOS 7) hosting Laravel and database is hosted in RDS. Staging environment is working perfectly fine.

I then cloned the EC2 and RDS for production and for unknown reason my Laravel keeps complaining that connection to database times out. Things I've tried:

1. Since I can run `mysql -u<username> -p<password>` and connect successfully then it means that Security Group and database permission are fine.
2. I also ensured that the `.env` file contains the correct connection info.
3. Laravel is also able to list out the correct environment variables.
4. Lastly, I scanned through the code to ensure that there's no database connection hardcoded.

I don't know what else I missed out.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: Check cloudwatch logs too to see if you have too many connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple. It was very silly of me to miss out a backend instance. Once that was sorted out, the error disappeared.